# Passing props when creating child component

Tags: angular

I'm quite new to Angular 6 (coming from 1.3 and React) and I'm facing some issues when trying to simply pass down a prop to a child component.

Here's my parent component .ts

```
import { Component, Input, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardButtonComponent } from '../modals/dashboard-button/dashboard-button.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-dashboard-content',
  templateUrl: './admin-dashboard-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-dashboard-content.component.css']
})
export class AdminDashboardContentComponent {

  title: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.title="menu #1";
  }
}
```

I've tried to initialize the title both in the constructor or in the definition but it doesn't work either way. I was quite sure that was not the problem though.

Here's its .html:

```
<div class="dashboard-container">
  <div class="buttons-container">
    <app-dashboard-button [title]="title"></app-dashboard-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the child component. Ts:

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-button',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-button.component.css']
})
export class DashboardButtonComponent{

  @Input()
  title: string;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

html:

```
<div class="dashboard-button-container">
    {{title}}
</div>
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'title: undefined'. Current value: 'title: undefined'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
```

I'm probably missing something stupid about how the component lifecycle works but I think I need someone to point me in the right direction here. Thanks.

Comment: you can add `?` operator to prevent undefined `{{title?}}`

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a stackblitz?

Comment: @cyberpirate92 I just reproduced it on stackblitz and it doesn't show the error here so now I'm even more confused (???) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5edwsc

Comment: The code you have posted can't possibly produce that error, I can see that you have imported `ChangeDetectorRef` in your child component, did you omit posting any code?

Comment: No that was for debug purposes. Anyway the AdminDashboardContentComponent is passed dynamically to a template in another parent component. If I put the DashboardButtonComponent on that same level the error doesn't show up.